# iframes and mixed content in IE

Tags: ajax, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

My goal is to embed this webpage "brokercheck.finra.org/Search/Search.aspx"  into a visualforce page. I'm using an `<apex:iframe/>` to do this. I've tried  html iframes too.

In IE8, I'm getting a message saying  "do you want to view the webpage that was delivered securely"  the http content only works if the user clicks no. (which is not a good practice).

on the bottom of the page I'm getting a warning that says:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Message: Permission denied
Line: 6
Char: 152
Code: 0
URI: http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js
```

Is there anything I can do on my end to get around the popup?

I've tried a few things, but nothing has been fruitful...

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing an encrypted (https) content of visualforce / regular salesforce pages with unencrypted http. And sadly this website doesn't seem to have a secure version.

I'm afraid there's not much you can do, this "mixed content" warning is just a feature of IE. In fact I think it'd be pointless if websites could somehow suppress it ;) You can read about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the simplest thing is to ask users to [modify their security settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx).

You could try playing with Javascript, maybe loading content from finfra with some AJAX call... But that will be most likely treated by IE as cross-domain JavaScript and also blocked. Can you maybe simply show this page as a link / popup window? Or simply make REST GET call(s) to it server-side and display pieces of content?